# Stripping @ tags from a string in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use regex to remove @tags from a string in python however when i try to do this

```
str = ' you @warui  and @madawar '
h = re.search('@\w*',str,re.M|re.I)
print h.group()
```

It outputs only the first @tag.

```
@warui
```

and when i try it on http://regexr.com?304a6 it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re.search()` will only match one occurrence of the pattern.  If you want to find more, try using `re.findall()`.

Answer (score 5):

**"to use regex to remove @tags from a string"**

```
import re

text = ' you @warui  and @madawar '
stripped_text = re.sub(r'@\w+', '', text)
# stripped_text == ' you   and  '
```

or do you want to *extract* them?

```
import re

text = ' you @warui  and @madawar '
tags = re.findall(r'@\w+', text)
# tags == ['@warui', '@madawar']
```

A @tag is defined as `@` followed by *at least* one alphanumeric character, that's why `@\w+` is better than `@\w*`. Also you don't need to modify the case-sensitiveness, because `\w` matches both lower and upper characters.

Comment: If you really wants to remove the tags you probably also want to use `r'@\w+\W'` to strip the unnecessary trailing whitespace of a tag.

Comment: @Kimvais - although this not a bad idea, it might need a little bit more logic to be built correctly: `hello @world, how are you?` -> `hello , how are you?` (`hello, how are you?` would be a better result)

Comment: better to strip the leading whitespace then :) `r'\W@\w+'`

Answer (score 3):

```
import re
s = ' you @warui  and @madawar '
for h in re.findall('@\w*',s,re.M|re.I):
  print h
```

Prints:

> @warui
>
> @madawar